# Custom Spring Data JPA @Query not working for Postgres JsonB ignoring parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I have a Postgres table with a json blob column -

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    id serial primary key,
    data jsonb
);
```

With a couple of records -

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, data)
VALUES (1,'{"num": "123", "status": "DRAFT"}');

INSERT INTO mytable (id, data)
VALUES (2,'{"num": "456", "status": "LIVE"}');
```

I'm able to select using the json keys 'num' and 'status' like this -

```
SELECT * FROM mydb.public.mytable WHERE data @> '{"num": "123", "status": "DRAFT"}';
```

I am trying to put this into a custom query with the values for 'num' and status as parameters -

```
@Repository
interface MyRepository : CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
@Query("SELECT * FROM mydb.public.mytable WHERE data @> '{\"num\" :num, \"status\" :status}'")
  fun findByNumAndStatus(num: String, status: String) : List<MyEntity>
}
```

But I'm getting zero results when I run the query.
I think it's ignoring the parameters `:num` and `:status`, because when I hardcode the values '123' and 'DRAFT' it works as expected.

As an update I've also tried these queries -

```
SELECT t.* FROM mydb.public.mytable t WHERE CAST(t.data ->> 'num' AS VARCHAR) = :num;
SELECT * FROM mydb.public.mytable WHERE data@> :num; --'{"num":"123"}'
SELECT* FROM mydb.public.mytable where data #>> '{num}' = :num;
```

*of course they only use a single parameter*

They work when I execute them in my db client, but return no results when I use them in my `@Query(..)` annotation.

Can anybody spot what I have done wrong with my query/function in the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working!
Here is the solution -

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t.* FROM mydb.public.mytable t" +
               "WHERE CAST(t.data ->> 'num' AS VARCHAR) = :num" +
               "AND CAST(t.data ->> 'status' AS VARCHAR) = :status",
       nativeQuery = true)
fun findByNumAndStatus(@Param("num") num: String, @Param("status") status: String): List<MyEntity>
```

The key points to get it working are -

- use `nativeQuery=true`
- use of `@Param(..)` annotations
- use of `CAST(..)` in the query for the parameters
- specifying the full path to the table `dbname.schemaname.tablename`, in my case `mydb.public.mytable`